# Calculating density of individuals within an area (tree stand density)

Tags: functions, problem-solving, area, density-function

**Any help greatly appreciated!**

I want to find the density of trees surrounding a sample point (measured in trees/m$^2$).

The distance from the sample point to the three nearest trees has been measured. I derived tree density via the formulae:

**1. mean of the distances between sample points and the 3 nearest trees (in meters)**

**2. mean area = mean distance $^2$**

**3. tree density = $\frac{1} {mean area}$**

e.g. distance between sample point and 3 nearest trees = 1m,2m and 3m
mean distance = 2m, mean area = 4m$^2$, tree density = 0.25 trees/ m$^2$.

However, I found another source that suggested another equation:

**Density = √$ \frac{mean area} {2}$**

There is no explanation why the mean area is over 2.

My question is:

How is the last formulae a valid means of finding density? Surely by square rooting the area/ 2, you find a distance value in metres instead of no. of trees/m$^2$?

What does the number 2 symbolise or function as in this equation?

This would be very helpful to know to help me understand which is the preferable equation to use.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please format your questions using MathJax.  [This page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.

Comment: Thanks for the link to basic MathJax.

Comment: Upon further research, I found that the 2 value is a conversion factor. This is included in the equation to improve the accuracy of the density calculation.